# URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I am developing a web application using an executable jar with embedded Jetty.
My jar contains a dependent jar.(jar in jar)
I referenced to the `JarRsrcLoader` and `RsrcURLStreamHandlerFactory` that developed by Eclipse.
`JarRsrcLoader` is using `URL#setURLStreamHandlerFactory(RsrcURLStreamHandlerFactory)` to resolve `rsrc` protocol.
Thereby it can resolve class path for jar.
But it becomes impossible to solve the usual protocol as side effects.
for example `file:xxxx` or `jar:xxxx`.
`RsrcURLStreamHandlerFactory` has `setURLStreamHandlerFactory` method.
Maybe I think I should set the default implement to this method.
I don't know what set this method.

Comment: are you running your application inside Equinox(OSGi container)?

Comment: It's weird. "file" is implemented by JRE, JRE should search it in its package if your factory doesn't know 'file'. See URL.getURLStreamHandler() or debug it.

Comment: I agree. We can consider URL.getURLStreamHandler as "strange". The factory has the priority over other protocols, except if an handler is already present in its cache. Weird really, at least inconsistent.

Answer (score 11):

There is only one instance of a `URLStreamHandlerFactory` implementation registered into the Java runtime, so this implementation must be aware of all supported protocols.

The default Oracle/Sun behavior is not implemented that way but directly in the `java.net.URL` class. So you cannot simply inject a default implementation as a chained factory in `RsrcURLStreamHandlerFactory`. First part of the answer.

The `java.net.URL` `getURLStreamHandler` method loads an implementation for a protocol `X` according to the naming policy of its class name, by default as `sun.net.www.protocol.X.Handler`

If you look at `jre/lib/rt.jar`, you will find:

```
sun/net/www/protocol/ftp/Handler.class
sun/net/www/protocol/gopher/Handler.class
sun/net/www/protocol/mailto/Handler.class
sun/net/www/protocol/netdoc/Handler.class
sun/net/www/protocol/http/Handler.class
sun/net/www/protocol/jar/Handler.class
sun/net/www/protocol/file/Handler.class
```

The list of base packages used for the protocol `URLStreamHandler` selection comes from the `java.protocol.handler.pkgs` Java system property. I invite you to read the full source code of the `java/net/URL.java` from the JDK `src.zip` to understand details.

- So the right way to do it (whatever IBM/Eclipse did) is to leave the default mechanism in place and set for instance `-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs="com.company.product.protocol"` on the command-line (if you have permission/accreditation to do so). With a `URLStreamHandler` implementation named `com.company.product.protocol.rsrc.Handler` that uses `JarRsrcLoader`, you get the job done.
- The alternate option is to write a `URLStreamHandlerFactory` implementation as a chained factory in `RsrcURLStreamHandlerFactory` inspired from `URL.getURLStreamHandler` source code. As an example, you can read [this old JBoss code](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/net/protocol/URLStreamHandlerFactory.java.html). It relies on `URL` internal handlers cache by preloading other *known* (or *used*) protocols before registering the factory. In my opinion, just ugly.

**Warning**: `RsrcURLStreamHandler` has replaced the original 180-lines-of-code of `URLStreamHandler.parseURL` by its own 10-lines "version" without calling `super.parseURL`. For sure it does not respect URL concatenation specifications ! Take care, you may face a bug depending on the way such URLs are used.

Comment: Thanks for reference to the old JBoss code. I actually used it one and I was suprised when I have to add call to the `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory()` when I started JBosss microcontainer (for running JUnit). :-)

Comment: It's not true that the one installed URLStreamHandlerFactory needs to know all protocols, it may return "null" and the URL class will try other sources. The only problem with the current factory approach is, that it can only be registered once and all others need to fallback to the system property or else. Pretty bad design. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/net/URL.java#URL.getURLStreamHandler%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I cannot confirm on which Java and Eclipse versions these investigations had been done... but I guess this null-to-default-fallback behavior is a "recent" change to work-around that issue.

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 9 you can use SPI to provide handlers:

[URL(String, String, int, String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-java.lang.String-) constructor JavaDoc describing search algorithm:

> 1. If the application has previously set up an instance of URLStreamHandlerFactory as the stream handler factory, then the createURLStreamHandler method of that instance is called with the protocol string as an argument to create the stream protocol handler.
> 2. **If no URLStreamHandlerFactory has yet been set up, or if the factory's createURLStreamHandler method returns null, then the ServiceLoader mechanism is used to locate [URLStreamHandlerProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/spi/URLStreamHandlerProvider.html) implementations using the system class loader.** The order that providers are located is implementation specific, and an implementation is free to cache the located providers. A ServiceConfigurationError, Error or RuntimeException thrown from the createURLStreamHandler, if encountered, will be propagated to the calling thread. The createURLStreamHandler method of each provider, if instantiated, is invoked, with the protocol string, until a provider returns non-null, or all providers have been exhausted.
> 3. If the previous step fails to find a protocol handler, the constructor reads the value of the system property:
>      java.protocol.handler.pkgs
> 4. If the previous step fails to find a protocol handler, then the constructor tries to load a built-in protocol handler. If this class does not exist, or if the class exists but it is not a subclass of URLStreamHandler, then a MalformedURLException is thrown.
>
> Protocol handlers for the following protocols are guaranteed to exist on the search path : http, https, file, and jar

Comment: Finally a reason to upgrade!